# How can I list the packages I removed on a specific day?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, purge

On May 05, 2016, I had removed some packages from my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. Now I want to make a list of those packages which I had removed on that day. How can I do it using **Terminal**?

However, I can get these info from **Ubuntu Software Center > History > Removals**. But I'm wishing to get a plain text file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this line:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "2016-05-05" | grep "remove" | grep -v "startup"
```

And for putting it into a file:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "2016-05-05" | grep "remove" | grep -V "startup" > removed-files.txt
```

There are surely multiple and maybe even more elegant ways of doing this, if you point them out I'll add them to my answer here.

Comment: I understand the command looks for files from "2016-05-05" and files containing "remove" but what does grep -v "startup" do?